# best way to find sum of powers of prime factors of a number

Tags: recurrence-relations, prime-factorization

What is the best way to find the sum of powers of prime factors of a number?

What I did till now is
:

```
for p in primes below limit:
    for v divisible by p
       ans[v] = ans[v] + power of p in v
```

This is working good when limit is $10^6$

I am interested to know if there is algorithm or recurrence to achieve this in a better way ?

Comment: Which power of $p$ do you intend to use?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman for example 12 = 2^2*3^1 then when p=2 i am talking about 2 and when p=3 I am talking about 1

Comment: So you want to calculate $\displaystyle\sum_i {e_i}$, if $n=\displaystyle\prod_i {p_i}^{e_i}$?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman Yes

Comment: Here's a page that talks about it, where it's called $\Omega(n)$: http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega(n),_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_(with_multiplicity) . And the OEIS page is https://oeis.org/A001222 .